# How to show checkboxes checked and update database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, checkbox

I have 80 checkboxes on my page ; these checkboxes belongs to  some options for product..

i store them like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $row['value]?>"/>
```

**DataBase Structure**

```
**Product_id** | **Option_id**
     1                 16
     1                 45
     1                 68
     1                 78
     1                 80
```

the question is , how should i update options? when user go update page , user should able to see checked options and unchecked too.. How can i show checked options?

i store  option values in database too ,  like this

```
**id** | **Option_id** |
   1         16
   2         45
   3         68
   4         78      
   ....
   ....
   80
```

Thank you very much for your help , sorry for my english..

Have a nice day

Comment: You want to know how to show them checked or how to store the checked or how to update them according to the checked ?

Comment: i want to know how to show them checked on the update page , and later update mysql table with new checked or unchecked values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To show them checked on the Front End**

Let's say that you have the result of the product's options in array called `$checked`

while looping the checked to print them use this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $row['value']?>" <?php if(in_array($row['value'], $checked)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; }?>/>
```

**For the update there is a lot of ways the simplest one is to**

Remove all the options and then add the new checked one

Hope this will help

Comment: Sorry i am late but shouldn't the code like this <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $row['value']?>" <?php if(in_array($row['value'], $checked)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; }?>/>

Comment: you are missing one ")" after if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
How can i show checked options?
```

You can use `checked="checked"` attribute to make a check box checked.

```
how should i update options?
```

Assume that you update the options which are belongs to product 1. What you have to do is delete the existing options and re insert the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should use database structure like this

`**User_id** | **Product_id** | **Option_id** | **State**`

for option values storing (cause each option is associated with certain user and product),
and use checkbox state values from database when rendering checkboxes:

`<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<?= ($row['State] ? "checked": "unchecked") ?>"/>`

Database updating means performing server-side UPDATE-queries based on the actual states of checkboxes through sending of the AJAX request on checkbox changing event, or through sending POST-request after total form submitting.